# Use macro to copy & transform data

Tags: excel, vba, copy, transform

I'm trying to copy data from a pivot table to another location such that the data in in columnar form where each "account number" is tied to its "cost center" and its associated "amount." The image below shows visually what I'm trying to achieve. I've used the "record macro" feature and it works.

However, the code is very long and I'm pretty sure it won't be dynamic for changes in pivot table size. 
So I thought I'd ask for help here.

If the code is straightforward and someone is will to share I'd appreciate it. Or, if someone can point me in the correct direction I'd appreciate that too!
Thank you for your time and expertise!

[image]

Comment: Actually it is only possible to help you with your code if you show it.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I'm having a hard time knowing where to start. Are there some methods/functions/etc. I should be looking at to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Look for Unpivot: https://www.excel-university.com/unpivot-excel-data/

Comment: Awesome. Ok, that is what I had ended up doing since I am more familiar with Power Query. Glad that ended up being your recommendation as well. Thanks!